# How can I use my PS3 controller with my PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my PS3 controller on a PC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/using-ps3-controller-on-pc)

I have a Windows 7 PC and am having problems with my PS3 controller. Does anybody know how to get my PS3 controller linked up to my PC so I can play games?

I have looked online but there are loads of different sites with conflicting information.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an easy thing to do, if at all possible. Xbox controllers work since they're MS like Windows..but PS3 controllers are Sony, so I doubt there'll be an easy way.

Comment: There is a signed driver called MotionInJoy that will allow your Dualshock 3 to work with your PC, but it isn't an official solution from Sony or Microsoft. My personal experience with the driver resulted in lots of BSODs until I removed it. Even though I prefer the DS3, I now use a wired Xbox360 controller when I need a gamepad to play games on my PC since it works without any hassle.

Comment: This has been asked before over here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/using-ps3-controller-on-pc, but there was no mention of potential BSODs.

Comment: Again, I know of several people who have MotionInJoy working with no issues at all. On MY system though, the driver worked, but I also had BSODs every 20 mins. I removed the driver and they stopped. I just put that down to an incompatibility between the driver and my motherboard/bluetooth usb dongle.

Answer (score 4):

They do not work wirelessly as I recall but if you use the USB cord, they have always just shown up as a generic controller for me.

Comment: Wouldn't you need some kind of driver for it to work with misc. games?

Comment: It may be that some of it wont work (rumble or the like) but as a general controller Windows in general has no problem picking it up and letting you use it.

Comment: In that case, +1