# Using a PS3 controller in the PC version of Far Cry 3

Tags: pc, controllers, far-cry-3, motioninjoy-ds3tool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my PS3 controller on a PC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/can-i-use-my-ps3-controller-on-a-pc)

I have recently bought Far Cry 3 for the PC but I can't play well with the keyboard. I have a PS3 controller, so I decided to try using it with MotioninJoy's [Ds3 Tool](http://www.motioninjoy.com/).

The problem is that the game doesn't let me play with it. Far Cry 3 has the option in the settings to use a gamepad, but it doesn't seem to pick up the PS3 controller.

Do I need to do something else? Or is it not possible to play with a PS3 controller?

Comment: @BenBrocka I know that I can use a ps3 controler on a PC and I am saying that in my question

Answer (score 1):

You [can play it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45610/how-to-use-your-ps-3-controllers-as-a-joystick-for-your-windows-pc/) with a ps3 controller, you just need some special drivers.

You can save yourself the headache and get a [Logitech F-510](http://www.logitech.com/de-de/product/7359) for [F-310](http://www.logitech.com/de-de/product/gamepad-f310?crid=713) (same pad, but no rumble) which is [XInput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput#XInput) compatible and looks/feels like a PS3 Controller. Any other XInput compatible GamePad works the same way.

**XInput compatible means you can play all games which claim "XBOX Support" without hassle.**

Comment: I am not interested in buying any new controller right now. It is a good proposal but it's not what I am asking. I have downloaded the drivers before I asked this question and I have followed the guide so I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: You asked if it is possible to play with a ps3 controller and I gave you an answer and a workaround. If that is not enough for you, you might wanna be more clear about what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping the buttons on the controller to keys on the keyboard- instead of using the joypad option in-game?

I'm not sure whether the drivers you are using allows different mapping, the drivers/program I use is [MotioninJoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/), and i can change the mapping like this:

[image: A screenshot of the MotioninJoy Button mapping screen, listing all the PS3 buttons, with drop lists next to them for changing which key is bound to it]

Comment: I haven't tried that but how did you go at these options. I remember I have gone there too but for some reason I can't now. Can you tell me how?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking, how to get to this screen? I'm pretty sure you click the 'Profiles' tab and add a new profile or 'edit' an existing one or something. I can check properly when I'm on my laptop later

Answer (score -1):

1. Have motionjoy running
2. Have xpadder running and your keys set up

when you insert your PS3 controller, it says 'driver installing', make sure you install motionjoy its drivers, otherwise it won't work