# How can I use an Arcade Stick designed for the PS3 on my PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

I have a Hori Real Arcade Pro 3 SF4 Edition Arcade Stick for PS3. It looks similar to this:

[image]

Is it possible to use this with my PC? To be specific, I would like to use this with Super Street Fighter 4: Arcade Edition, which I've installed through Steam.

Comment: We're not here to test compatibility issues for you.  If you run into a problem getting it to work, we can help you with that, though.

Comment: Just plug it in and see if it's listed as an input device. I have a PS3 stick from Madcatz and it works as an input device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use my PS3 controller on a PC?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/can-i-use-my-ps3-controller-on-a-pc)

Answer (score 1):

If it is designed for use with the PS3, you can try using [Motioninjoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/).

Motioninjoy lets you use your PS3 Dualshock 3 or Sixaxis controller on your PC. It can even emulate an Xbox controller for games that natively support it. Check out this guide for more info:

[How to use a PS3 controller on a PC](http://www.gamefront.com/how-to-use-a-ps3-controller-on-a-pc/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's wireless then you may have difficulty finding drivers that will work with it. Unfortunately, PS3 peripherals don't work natively on Windows in the same way that many Xbox accessories do.

There are some helpful guides and resources for syncing DualShock 3 controllers. That might be your best bet in finding a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work according to this guy:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1996426

> im using an HORI real arcade pro 3 (ps3) and its working flawless

I have personally used two different sets of PS3 joysticks and both work on the PC no problem.